# Python and sqlite3 - Not adhering to Pragmas (foreign key constraints, unique, etc)

Tags: python, sqlite

During testing I realised that when using sqlite3 with Python it doesn't seem to follow the pragma settings as set out in the database.

For example, when inserting new records into the database using Python I can insert data that should trigger a foreign key constraint error. When inserting the same information with DB Browser for SQLite the foreign key constraint error is triggered as expected.

How do I go about ensuring it follows the pragma and all other rules such as UNIQUE, NOT NULL, etc. Additionally why doesn't it adhere to these rules by default, I can't think of a reason why it wouldn't follow them.

Comment: The pragma settings are not persisted in the database. You must set them on each connection.

Comment: @forpas thank you, do you know how I go about doing that for all pragma settings?

Comment: From a simple google search: https://www.programcreek.com/python/?CodeExample=set+sqlite+pragma